# Angular JS Objects vs Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create an object with 3 properties inside. However, every time I run the code it will only display the code expression. How do array and objects affect each other?

My code:

```js
var app = angular.module("FundAllocation", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.AllocFunds = [{Name:'Groceries',AllFunds:'2'},
        {Name:'Travel',AllFunds:'2'},
        {Name:'House',AllFunds:'2'}
       ];
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in AllocFunds">
    row: {{row.Name}
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: You are missing the final curly brace after`row.name`; is that typo in your real code?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second curly brace in your HTML `{{row.Name}`. A missing curly brace won't display any errors and will just display what it literally is, in this case "{{row.Name}". The rest of your code seems fine and should work.

Comment: hi guys, even if I put the 2nd curly brace. it still wont work. :(

Comment: @ZackAthonBusiness Can you post your full code? Also check if the console is displaying any errors.

Comment: I did check the console and gave me this error. Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp%0AL%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A425%0AAe%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A270%0Ab%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A299%0AAe%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A

Comment: @ZackAthonBusiness Try using angular that hasn't been minified (usually removing .min from your script src will work). This will display a longer and more detailed error.